# Enum has not been declared?

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error. It's like the compiler does not recognise my declarations

```
 g++ -c main.cc
In file included from Storage.h:7:0,
                 from Server.h:5,
                 from Control.h:8,
                 from main.cc:5:
Serializer.h:11:36: error: ‘Storage::UpdateType’ has not been declared
Serializer.h:12:45: error: ‘Storage::UpdateType’ has not been declared
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Anyone have an idea what this error is about because the enum has already beeen declared. The affected code is below:

Serializer.h

```
#ifndef SERIALIZER_H
#define SERIALIZER_H

#include "Storage.h"

class Storage;

class Serializer{
  public: 
    Serializer();
    void serialize(List&, Storage::UpdateType&, std::string&);
    void deserialize(std::string&, Storage::UpdateType&, List&);

};

#endif
```

Storage.h

```
#ifndef STORAGE_H
#define STORAGE_H 

#include "List.h"
#include "Interface.h"
#include "Movie.h"
#include "Serializer.h"

class Storage{
  public:
    enum UpdateType {ADD, DELETE, RETRIEVE};
    Storage();
    ~Storage();
    List* list;
    void retrieve(List*);
    void update(UpdateType, List*);
    void handleRequest(string&, string&);
  private:
    //Serializer serial;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Cyclic include dependency: `Storage.h` includes `Serializer.h` and vice versa. This cannot work.

Comment: no it does not, because it features the macro guards against circular dependency.

Comment: @zmo Yes it does. The guards don't fix this problem.

Comment: How can I get access to the enum in Storage in the Serializer class?

Comment: Include "Storage.h" in "Serializer.h" and forward declare `Serializer` in "Storage.h" (thus breaking the dependency.)

Comment: @juanchopanza the problem is not the "cyclic include dependency", it's the order of declaration… So maybe I'm mis-understanding what "cyclic include dependency" means, but to me it's when you have an infinite recursion over the includes.

Comment: @zmo Cyclic include dependency means that one thing includes another that includes it, forming a cycle. If A includes B and B includes A, it is a cyclic include dependency. It is quite simple.

Comment: well, then it's not cyclic, as A includes B that tries to include A, but actually is *not* including A because of the guards. *QED*

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your code is interpreted as follows:

```
#ifndef STORAGE_H
#define STORAGE_H 

// replacing the include with the Serializer.h file

#include "List.h"
#include "Interface.h"
#include "Movie.h"

// replacing the include with the Storage.h file
#ifndef STORAGE_H // returns true
#endif

class Storage;

class Serializer{
  public: 
    Serializer();
    // here Storage::UpdateType is still unknown to the compiler
    void serialize(List&, Storage::UpdateType&, std::string&);
    void deserialize(std::string&, Storage::UpdateType&, List&);

};

#endif


class Storage{
  public:
    // as it gets declared here
    enum UpdateType {ADD, DELETE, RETRIEVE};
    Storage();
    ~Storage();
    List* list;
    void retrieve(List*);
    void update(UpdateType, List*);
    void handleRequest(string&, string&);
  private:
    //Serializer serial;
};
#endif
```

the best solution, imho, would be to extract the `enum UpdateType` from your storage class and forward declare it in Serializer. Or even declare it within the Serializer header, as `Storage` is encapsulating `Serializer` stuff, so basically, the `UpdateType` stuff should be in the same encapsulated context as the `Serializer` stuff.

Another solution would be @Nim suggests, to include Storage from Serializer, forward declare Serializer in Storage and include Serializer in main. But it may deceives the way you have thought your design out, reversing the encapsulation of `Serializer` and `Storage`.

Finally, I'm *really* not sure if this is possible and how would be the syntax, but if it is, you could simply forward declare `enum Storage::UpdateType` in Serializer. And I guess that's what you wish would be possible.